# С чего правильно начинать разработку веб-приложения, с backend или frontend части?

Tags: php, html, javascript, веб-программирование

Если работаешь в одиночку.

Comment: Меня тоже этот вопрос интересует но задавать его было лень...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно продумать концепт — что будет в приложении, в каком виде и каким образом должен происходить обмен данными.

Честно говоря, не знаю, с чего начинать "правильно", но по моему, логично, что стоит начать с `backend` части. Как показывает опыт, так получается более логично и дополнения, которые появляются в процессе, дописываются легче. Потом уже делается `frontend` часть и связывается с самим "движком".

Хотя, думаю, это зависит от индивидуальных умений и предпочтений.